# Can we maintain a standing wave in a slowly growing box?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, string, quantum-states

I believed that the answer to that simple question was '*yes*', until I was thinking more about it recently, and now I have a doubt.

Consider a simple **standing wave** in a 1D "box" of length $a_0$.  It could be a simple mechanical wave propagating on a material elastic string of length $\ell = a_0$, an electromagnetic standing wave inside a metallic box, or a non-relativistic quantum particle moving back and forth between two infinite potential walls (i.e the "box").  The standing wave wavelenght is then $\lambda = 2 a_0 / n$, where $n = 1, 2, 3, \dots$ is the mode number.

Now we slowly raise the lenght of the box: $a_0 \Rightarrow a(t)$ (an exterior agent is doing some work here).  The question is then very simple:

Is it possible to slowly change the size of the box while keeping the standing wave number $n$ at the same time and having a variable wavelenght $\lambda \propto a(t)$, so the wave stays stationary while the box is changing?  If the answer is '*yes*', how can we justify that the process should be slow enough that
$$\tag{1}
\frac{da}{dt} \ll v_{\text{wave}}
$$

Comment: I don’t see the problem! The standing wave’s energy changes, and at the same time whatever is moving the walls does work.

Comment: @knzhou, I agree that it seems obvious.  I may erase that stupid question.  Can we say that this process is 'adiabatic'?  The oscillation frequency is decreasing, but what about the amplitude?  And why should the process be slow? Relative to what?

Comment: When we say a mechanical change is adiabatic, we mean that the conditions of the adiabatic theorem hold, which are quite unambiguous. For example, in this case, the fractional change of the length during one period of the standing wave should be small. The evolution of the amplitude can then be found using the adiabatic theorem.

Comment: @knzhou, I suggest that you state this theorem as an answer, showing the details for the process to be possible (and also the amplitude variation).  It should then be possible to demonstrate equation (1) above.

Comment: You can also look up *adiabatic theorem in quantum mechanics* in a search engine. There are plenty of resources out there.